# How to animate expand and shrink uiview in place?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a series of `uiviews`, and i want to create an animation where a button press event will expand the uiview from the bottom and reveal more information about the view. Another button press will shrink the view back to original.

How do i proceed with this?

There are a series of uiviews laid out in a horizontal scroll view like a coverflow. I want to display additional information about each uiview on click of a button.

Do drop a comment if you need more information.

TIA,

Praveen S

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code will expand your view...do the reverse to shrink it

```
CGRect tempFrame=view.frame;
tempFrame.size.width=200;//change acco. how much you want to expand
tempFrame.size.height=200;
[UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
view.frame=tempFrame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Great i will have a look at it.

Comment: sure...let me know the issues if any

Answer (score 1):

For that use this code

In .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ExpandedViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIView * expandiView;
    BOOL viewExpanded;
}
- (IBAction)expandOrShrinkView:(id)sender;
@end
```

and in your .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    aview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)];
    aview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:aview];

    viewExpanded = NO;
}
```

And in your button action add this code

```
- (IBAction)expandOrShrinkView:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations: ^{
        if (!viewExpanded) {
            viewExpanded = YES;
           aview.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 200);
        }else{
            viewExpanded = NO;
           aview.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);
        }
    } completion:nil];  
}
```

When you click the button first time it will expand the view from bottom and when you click the button second time it will shrink the View from bottom change the frame size to your need..

And if you want shrink function in another button than use two action method like this

```
- (IBAction)expandView:(id)sender {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations: ^{
               aview.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 200);
        } completion:nil];  
    }

- (IBAction)ShrinkView:(id)sender {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations: ^{
               aview.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);
        } completion:nil];  
    }
```

Comment: Using this i have to click my button twice to open the view. Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: @teuben have you add this line `viewExpanded = NO;` in the `ViewDidLoad` method? Bcoz i think problem is that you dont have seted the viewExpanded thats why when method called first time it will not opened the view. Check that and let me know

Comment: I do have the viewExpanded = NO; in the viewDidLoad. I found that it needs to be set to YES though. When its going to that action to expand it needs the if to evaluate to true so either the viewExpanded Bool needs to start at YES or the code in the action method needed to be reversed. -Thanks